# Existe um bug na edição de listas?

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Percebi que quando coloco um código abaixo de uma lista, ele não recebe a formatação a não ser que:

- retire a lista;
- Coloque um parágrafo e um caracter antes do código.

  $naoFunciona = "Retire a lista";
- retire a lista;
- Coloque um parágrafo e um caracter antes do código.

.

```
$assimFunciona = "????";
```

Comment: Já que é dup, só não sei onde.

Comment: Desta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4528/marcação-de-código-não-esta-funcionando-com-código-especifico/4531#4531

Comment: Tem uma diferença entre o que você fez e o que eu sugiro no link. O que eu disse vale para código dentro de itens de lista. A sua solução é para código *depois* da lista.

Comment: Não entendi qual a outra solução @bfavaretto, mas 8 espaços funcionou certinho para o depois da lista também. +1

Comment: Gustavo, editei a resposta na outra pergunta. Ficou mais clara e completa, acho que agora você vai entender o que eu disse acima.